# Apache Spark: How to perform cartesian product in map function of XML nodes

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark

I have an RDD of scala.xml.ELem values named mxml.

for each Elem I want to extract all the text related to two types of child nodes and form the cartesian product on a per Elem basis. on the REPL I can use the following code

```
val xmlnode = mxml.take(1)(0)
val a = (xmlnode \\ "NodeType1").map(_.text)
val b = (xmlnode \\ "NodeType2").map(_.text)
val c = sc.parallelize(a).cartesian(sc.parallelize(b))
```

and c gives me what I want, but requires me to use the spark contextto get the data I am interested in.

> how can I put this into a map function such that I could write

```
mxml.map(function)
```

am I basically going to be forced to do the first two steps and follow them up with a for loop to generate Tuple2s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple `flatMap` with for comprehension should do the trick:

```
mxml.flatMap { xmlnode => for {
  a <- xmlnode \\ "NodeType1"
  b <- xmlnode \\ "NodeType2"
} yield (a.text, b.text) }
```